# Redirecting user to a specified php based on his form inputs during registration

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a website built entirely using Twitter Bootstrap framework.Its a website that provides questions to the users of different engineering branches.However,is it possible that i took an input like "enginnering branch=user_engineering_branch" via registration form and redirect him to a page,after his successful login,that contains questions of his branch only instead showing up the entire questions.?

I coded the entire login/registration script using php so please provide the solution in php only.

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as simple as

```
if ($_POST['enginnering branch']=="user_engineering_branch") {
    $redirectURL="address/to/your/branch";
    header('Location: '.$redirectURL);
}
```